# не выводится html в Swift WebView

Tags: html, ios, веб-программирование, swift, view

Пишу приложение, возникла одна проблема в момент когда я открываю окно с WebView куда должен вывестись мой html приложение крашится 
Подскажитe,пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка,файл html добавлен в проект и связь переменной webView со storyboаrd тоже

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class AboutViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BullsEye", ofType: "html") {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath)
            let request = URLRequest(url: url)
            self.webView.load(request)
        }

    }

    @IBAction func close () {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

Comment: Что в консоли пишет?

Comment: libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class AboutViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let htmlPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BullsEye", ofType: "html") {
            do {
                let contents = try String(contentsOfFile: htmlPath, encoding: .utf8)
                let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: htmlPath)
                webView.loadHTMLString(contents as String, baseURL: url)
            }
            catch {
                   print("Ошибка вывода HTML файла")
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func close () {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func loadHtmlFile() {
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BullsEye", withExtension: "html") {
        let request = URLRequest.init(url: url)
        webView.load(request)
    } else {
        print ( "File reading error: \(debugDescription)")
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert!", message: "File reading error☠️", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: .default, handler: { action in
            switch action.style{
            case .default:
                print("default")

            case .cancel:
                print("cancel")

            case .destructive:
                print("destructive")


            }}))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

а затем в viewDidLoad() вызовите метод loadHtmlFile()